# How can i secure my web server

Tags: webserver

i want to secure my web-server from hackers. what are the ways for secure my web server? . I need tight security. without admin permission no one can not access or hack my web-server

Comment: What services and operating system are you running?

Comment: There are literally entire books on this kind of thing, and you'd likely need to read at least five to get a decent understanding of how this topic. This question is way too broad for a StackExchange site.

Comment: sorry i am new to web server , that why i am asking like this. here after i didn't do like this

Comment: @tamil_arvu If it was that easy to secure a webserver then there would be so few hacking cases and the security industry would have suffered from it :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at hardening checklists from NIST (https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/ncp/repository) or hardening benchmarks from Centre for Internet Security (http://CISecurity.org).

Harden your operating system, harden your application server, securely develop your application, restrict user access, test your security controls.

As @polynomial says above, your question is very broad. Look at guidance from the above sites and identify what will work for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Hardening RPM based distros [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html)

Take a look at this guide if you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS [Part 1](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)

always keep in mind that security is a ongoing processs and that there is no final state!

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: @HamZa fixed :)